# Laravel 6 the @yield() not working in include() method

Tags: jquery, laravel, layout, laravel-blade

**Why the `@yield('script')` doesn't work?**
I create a layout in PHP laravel Blade **master.blade.php** file like this

```
@include('layouts.header')
@include('layouts.sidebar')
<div class="main-panel">
    <!-- Navbar -->
@include('layouts.navbar')
<!-- End Navbar -->
    <div class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
@include('layouts.footer')
```

I add `@yield('script')` in `layouts.footer` for writing script code by using @section('script')
**layouts.footer** file

```
....
<script src="{{ asset('./assets/js/core/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
@yield('script')
...
  </body>
</html>
```

and when I use `section('script')` in the blade page it doesn't work
*I used `@yield('script')` like this*

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
   <div>
      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="modal">
              Sponsored
      </button>
   </div>
@endsection

// JQuery code 
@section('script')
    <script>
        $(document).on("click", "#modal", function () {
            alert('hello world');
        });
    </script>
    @endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blade allows you to push to named stacks which can be rendered somewhere else in another view or layout. This can be particularly useful for specifying any JavaScript libraries required by your child views:

This is the wrong way to `include` the `scripts` and `links`.

You can use `@stack` for it. more about [stack](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#stacks)

**layouts.footer** file

```
<script src="{{ asset('./assets/js/core/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
@stack('script')
```

**Blade** file

```
@push('script')
    <script>
        $(document).on("click", "#modal", function () {
            alert('hello world');
        });
    </script>
@endpush
```